# part of information of my customers are inserted in the database , while some are not

Tags: php, mysql

i am registering customers and the registration requires address, but the    'houseno','addressa','addressb','addressc','county','state','country' is not inserting in the database while the other information are inserting, after the customer has registered

```
<?php
echo "<h2>Register</h2>";

$submit = $_POST['register'];
//form data
$fullname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['fullname'])));
$username = strtolower(mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['username']))));
$password = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['password'])));
$repeatpassword = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['repeatpassword'])));
$email = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['email'])));
$houseno = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['houseno'])));
$addressa = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['addressa'])));
$addressb = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['addressb'])));
$addressc = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['addressc'])));
$county = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['county'])));
$state = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['state'])));
$country = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['country'])));
$accept = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['accept'])));

if ($submit)
{
$namecheck = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM reusers WHERE username='$username'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($namecheck);

if($count!=0)
{
die("Username already taken!");

}


//check for registration form details
    if ($fullname&&$username&&$password&&$repeatpassword&&$email&&$houseno&&$addressa&&$county&&$state&&$country)
{
if($accept == 1)
{
if ($password==$repeatpassword)
{
//check char lenght of username and fullname
if (strlen($username)>25||strlen($fullname)>25)
{
echo "Lenght of username or fullname is too long";
}
else
{
//check password length
if(strlen($password)>25||strlen($password)<6)
{
echo"Password must be between 6 and 25 characters";
}
else
{
//check password length
$emailcheck = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM reusers WHERE email='$email'");
$ecount = mysql_num_rows($emailcheck);
if($ecount!=0)
{
echo"email already registered Please sign in into your account to continue";
}
else
    {
       //generate random code
       $code = rand(11111111,99999999);

       //send activation email
       $to = $email;
       $subject = "Activate your account";
       $headers = "From: donotreply@rapsody.co.uk";
       $body = " Hello $fullname,\n\nUsername $username,\n\n Password $password ,\n\nYou registered and need to activate your account. Click the link below or paste it into the URL bar of your browser\n\nhttp://reacheasy.co.uk/activate.php?code=$code\n\nThanks!";

       if (!mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers))
           echo "We couldn't sign you up at this time. Please try again later.";

else

{
//register the user!
//encript password
$password = md5($password);
$repeatpassword = md5($repeatpassword);


$queryreg = mysql_query("

INSERT INTO reusers VALUES ('','$fullname','$username','$password','$email','$code','0','houseno','addressa','addressb','addressc','county','state','country')

");

die("You have been registered successfully! Please check your email ($email) to activate your account<a href='index.php'>Return to login page</a>");
}
}
}
}
}
else
    echo"Your passwords do not match!";

}
else
    echo"Please read and accept Terms and Conditions before registering!";
}
else
        echo "Please fill in <b>all</> fields!";

}
?>
</div>
<p>
<form action='reregister.php' method='Post' class='rl'>
    <div>
    <label for='fullname' class='fixedwidth'>Your full name*</label>
    <input type='text' name='fullname' id='username' value='<?php echo $fullname; ?>'/>
    </div>

    <div>
    <label for='username' class='fixedwidth'>Choose a user name*</label>
    <input type='text' name='username' id='username' value='<?php echo $username; ?>'/>
    </div>

    <div>
    <label for='password' class='fixedwidth'>Choose a password*</label>
    <input type='password' name='password' id='password'/>
    </div>

    <div>
    <label for='repeatpassword' class='fixedwidth'>Repeat your password*</label>
    <input type='password' name='repeatpassword' id='repeatpassword'/>
    </div>

    <div>
    <label for='email' class='fixedwidth'>E-mail*</label>
    <input type='text' name='email' id='email'/>
    </div>

    <h2>Personal details</h2>

    <div>
    <label for='houseno' class='fixedwidth'>HOUSE NAME/NO*</label>
    <input type='text' name='houseno' id='houseno' value='<?php echo $houseno; ?>' />
    </div>

    <div>
    <label for='addressa' class='fixedwidth'>ADDRESS LINE 1*</label>
    <input type='text' name='addressa' id='addressa' value='<?php echo $addressa; ?>' />
    </div>

    <div>
    <label for='addressb' class='fixedwidth'>ADDRESS LINE 2</label>
    <input type='text' name='addressb' id='addressb' value='<?php echo $addressb; ?>' />
    </div>

    <div>
    <label for='addressc' class='fixedwidth'>ADDRESS LINE 3</label>
    <input type='text' name='addressc' id='addressc' value='<?php echo $addressc; ?>' />
    </div>

    <div>
    <label for='county' class='fixedwidth'>COUNTY/LGA*</label>
    <input type='text' name='county' id='county' value='<?php echo $county; ?>' />
    </div>

    <div>
    <label for='state' class='fixedwidth'>STATE*</label>
    <input type='text' name='state' id='state' value='<?php echo $state; ?>' />
    </div>

    <div>
    <label for='country' class='fixedwidth'>COUNTRY*</label>
    <input type='country' name='country' id='country' value='<?php echo $country; ?>' />
    </div>

    <div>
    <input name="accept" type="checkbox" class="tickbox" value="1" />
    <a href="termsandcondition.php">Terms and Conditions</a>
    </div>

    <div class='buttonarea'>
            <p>
            <input type='submit' name='register' value='Register'>
            </p>
            </div>
            </p>

</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: consider using an orm framework such as Propel or Doctrine, it will save you a lot of manually escaping user input and most important, head aches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need a couple of $ in your SQL-query

```
$queryreg = mysql_query("
INSERT INTO reusers VALUES('','$fullname','$username','$password','$email','$code','0','houseno','addressa','addressb','addressc','county','state','country')
");
```

Should be changed to

```
$queryreg = mysql_query("
INSERT INTO reusers VALUES('','$fullname','$username','$password','$email','$code','0','$houseno','$addressa','$addressb','$addressc','$county','$state','$country')
");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `$` infront of the later variables, so you just insert "houseno" instead of the variable `$houseno`.